# How to design a c# class for both windows form and console app and also for web app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, web-applications, console-application

I have a class in c# for windows form application but they say I can make it generic in such a way so I can use it anywhere I want. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

My class is like that at the moment:

```
namespace nyp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

Comment: You could put that class into a seperate _class  library project_. I assume the class now resides directly within the WinForms project. If you put it into a class library, all your other projects (console, web, ...) can reference that class library and use the class.

Comment: ok thanks. but I hv looked for it in the menus but I couldn't see it. How can I do that putting process? I am lost in the VS at the moment :))

Comment: Add a project to the solution, Class Library

Comment: if your class is a partial that inherits of Form,  you have several problems.  By being partial it means its split into two parts, one code generated, the other your custom stuff. That needs to live in the same project.  Also if you depend on Form, then you can't really use it in a console app

Comment: @KeithNicholas I took a screen shot. http://i.hizliresim.com/YjqE4k.png is that ok?

Comment: wrong way around.  You want nyp to depend on your class Library

Comment: remove the reference from class library

Comment: @KeithNicholas I see what you mean but I think I don't have much time to re-design it. Thanks a lot anyway. I mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it into a Class Library Assembly, and add it as a Reference. That way you can use it in any .NET project.

However,  you can't make it depend on Windows Forms / Console API calls if you want it to be generic.  If you need a dependency on either then create an interface that abstracts away specific calls on Windows Forms / Console.

Two patterns to help you with that,  Dependency Injection and Adapter.